Is there a way to relatively import python files within a module so that the execution context may change without needing to update the import path?
Take the following python project structure:
project/
├── package/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
└── main.py

my main.py looks like:
import package

my module1.py looks like:
def some_fn():
    print("hi")


inside __init__.py, I would like to import module1.py.
init.py option 1- relative import:
from . import module1

module1.some_fn()

the problem: This works fine if I execute python main.py, but not if I execute python package/__init__.py
Option 2: explicit import
import package.module1

module1.some_fn()

the problem: The same as previous. This works fine if I execute python main.py, but not if I execute python package/__init__.py
Is there a way to do a relative import, so that I use two different execution contexts and still successfully import modules?
